# Background Image doesn't show on Windows 7 Browsers

Tags: css, windows-7, background-image

I've developed a really basic site for a friend of the family. It's very nearly ready to go bar one small issue on Windows 7 browsers.

I'm not very experienced designing for the Windows 7 platform and have struck a blank. I've also not got my own Windows 7 machine and have to check at work, making it tricky to debug.

Here's the URL-

pipecoproducts.com

The issue is with the background images, they show on all other platforms I test, but not Windows 7. The image was created in photoshop adding a white wash over it to let the content show over the top. It been saved as a png file.

Here's the CSS used to bring up the background-image, but I don't see why Windows 7 browsers don't like it-

```
#main {
    background-image:url("/img/backgrounds/pipeco.png");
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

Does anyone have any way of resolving this?

Thanks in advance.

Nick

Comment: Which Windows 7 browsers have you tried it on? Seems to be working fine in Firefox on Win 7.

Comment: I've tried Safari, FF, Chrome and IE. I'll give it another go tomorrow  now I've reduced the file sizes.

Answer (score 2):

Tested this on my Windows 7 PC on Internet Explorer 9, Chrome, and Firefox, the image works here without any problem.

It seems that the problem lays on your side and not on your code, although I've noticed your background image is 1MB, which is really huge for a background, perhaps the image stops loading due size or you haven't waited long enough.

Comment: Ah I see. I hadn't considered the size of the file. I will look for ways to reduce that then. I'm not sure I saw any sign of the page still loading though, I will check tomorrow and look for issues relating to my browser then. It's reassuring to know it's working for somebody at least. Thank you.

Comment: Also, just wanted to comment that in general browser's functionality is consistent from one platform to another (although the rendered page may differ slightly).

Comment: I certainly hadn't realised this - would you expand on it? Are you saying that for the same version of FF (for example) the capabilities will be exactly the same on Windows machines/Mac? So as to say it is the browser version that counts?

Comment: Yes, that's more or less the case. There may be some minor differences between platforms (for instance, the fonts installed on Linux may be different to those on Windows, so pages may look slightly different), but it's unusual to have major differences between the same browser on different platforms. It's much more common to have differences between different browsers, even if they're running on the same OS.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a possibility your work computer/network has some sort of web filtering software that could be preventing access to the image file?

Otherwise, as EliotVU says, 1MB is much too big, especially for a background image. On a slow connection it might just be taking so long to load that you think it isn't going to appear.

Comment: I've managed to reduce the images to roughly 400k by changing it to a low quality GIF. I don't know whether anyone knows how to get it smaller than that, feel free to pitch in if so. The page definitely finished loading though.

Comment: Does the background image display if you access it directly through your Windows 7 browsers - i.e. navigating straight to http://pipecoproducts.com/img/backgrounds/pipeco.gif?